# Должна ли предметная модель совпадать с базой данных по структуре?

Tags: база-данных, entity-framework

Вопрос возник при изучении подходов к разработке с Entity Framework (Database first, Model first). Сложилось впечатление, что **предметная модель** (со своими классами, свойствами) это полное отражение **базы данных** (с соответствующими таблицами, полями). Всегда ли предметная модель идентична базе данных по своей структуре? Поясните, пожалуйста, на конкретном примере.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не обязательно.

### Мы можем давать различные названия связанным классам и таблицам, также и полям.

Пример, таблица `Automobile` имеет своё отражение в классе `Car`, колонка таблицы `Maker` имеет своё отражение в свойстве `Brand`:

```
[Table("Automobile")]
class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("Maker")]
    public string Brand { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set;}
}
```

### Мы можем в наши классы добавить какие-то вспомогательные поля (которых не будет в БД).

Маленький выдуманный пример, имеем колонку `Specification` в БД, в которой у нас хранится описание в разметке markdown (отражение в классе `MarkdownSpecification`, а мы в нашем классе делаем вспомогательное поле, которое преобразует markdown к html - это поле не будет храниться в БД (`HtmlSpecification`).

```
[Table("Automobile")]
class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("Maker")]
    public string Brand { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set;}

    [Column("Specification")]
    public string MarkdownSpecification { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string HtmlSpecification 
    {
        get
        {
            string result; 
            //to html
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

### Мы можем использовать наследование в нашей модели.

В данном случае есть несколько подходов:

#### 1. Таблица на всю иерархию

Для родителя и наследника будет создана одна таблица и в ней будут перечисления всех полей и родителя и наследника

#### 2. Таблица на тип

Для родителя будет создана таблица с его набором колонок, для потомка с его набором колонок плюс ключ от родителя

#### 3. Таблица на конкретный тип

Для родителя будет своя таблица с его набором колонок, для потомка его таблица со всеми его колонками и унаследованными колонками

Пример, **таблица на иерархию**, в данном примере будет создана одна таблица `Vehicles`, в которой будут перечислены все свойства из двух классов:

```
class Vehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}

class Car : Vehicle
{
    public Model { get; set; }
}

class VehicleContext : DbContext
{
    public VehicleContext() : base("Connection name")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

Пример, **таблица на тип**, здесь используется `TableAttribute`, в данном случае будет создано две таблицы: `Vehicles` со всеми свойствами и `Cars` с Id и всеми свойствами объявленными в нём:

```
class Vehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}

[Table("Cars")]
class Car : Vehicle
{
    public Model { get; set; }
}

class VehicleContext : DbContext
{
    public VehicleContext() : base("Connection name")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

Пример, **Таблица на конкретный тип**, здесь  вызывается `MapInheritedProperties` в контексте под каждый класс, который для которого должна быть создана отдельная таблица со всеми полями (и своими, и унаследованными):

```
class Vehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}

class Car : Vehicle
{
    public Model { get; set; }
}

class VehicleContext : DbContext
{
    public VehicleContext() : base("Connection name")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Vehicles");
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Cars");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не всегда.

Например, в базе хранится информация о товаре. При этом, для сайта имеется своя модель, для бухов своя, для манагеров своя. И каждая из этих моделей может оперировать частью данных БД. Бухам не нужна картинка, а сайту величина налогов.

Далее, каждый более-менее большой, сложный проект денормализует данные. Это если мы говорим о реляционных БД. Навскидку: есть одежда, у одежды есть размер. Есть товар "Платье" которое производится в трех размерах: 43, 48, 52.
Я знаю, что мне не надо будет по размеру делать выборки (найти всю одежду 43 размера) или эти выборки будут очень редко. Я могу хранить в БД размеры в строку в одном поле: "43,48,52", а в моделях разворачивать каждый размер в отдельный объект, подчиненный "Платью". Даже этот притянутый за уши пример, может быть вполне реальным, когда размеры надо конвертить в локальные пользовательские стандарты и в стандарты производителей. Хранить удобно так, а логика просится в целый отдельный класс.

ORM, даже из названия, заточены на отображение объектов на БД. И если говорить именно об ORM, то они будут стремиться к этому. Такова их природа. Вы расплачиваетесь гибкостью за удобство. В какой-то момент приходится решать, что важнее и как дальше жить :)